# AWS ec2 fails to read csv file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/input/real/trca.csv'

Tags: python, linux, pandas, amazon-ec2, permission-denied

Recently I use AWS ec2 to deploy my python code. However, it always reports it cannot read .csv data because of permission issue as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 381, in <module>
    trcaData = np.asmatrix(pd.read_csv(datadir + "trca.csv").values)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 605, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 814, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1045, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1862, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1363, in _open_handles
    storage_options=kwds.get("storage_options", None),
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 647, in get_handle
    newline="",
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/input/real/trca.csv'
```

I tries to use any possible ways on websites but still failed. When I check the permission at each directory, the results looks like good.

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX KFSGPS2]$ ls -ld /home/
drwxr-xr-x 3 ec2-user root 22 Oct 26 15:35 /home/
[ec2-user@ip-XXX KFSGPS2]$ ls -ld /home/ec2-user
drwx------ 7 ec2-user ec2-user 153 Feb  2 00:34 /home/ec2-user
[ec2-user@ip-XXX KFSGPS2]$ ls -ld /home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/
drwxrwxr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 196 Feb  1 23:35 /home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/
[ec2-user@ip-XXX KFSGPS2]$ ls -ld /home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/input/
drwxrwxr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 51 Feb  1 22:13 /home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/input/
[ec2-user@ip-XXX KFSGPS2]$ ls -ld /home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/input/real/
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 55 Feb  1 22:13 /home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2/input/real/
```

Any idea can fix this? Really appreciated.

Comment: How did you create your file? How do you access it? What users did you use for that?

Comment: @Marcin, I add the directories into program.py file and then use condor command (condor_submit mytest.sub) to submit my jobs. All those related files (uploaded by cyberduck) are under /home/ec2-user/KFSGPS2. I am an greenhand on this, so what do you mean "create file" and "access it" ? I just log in with SSH and type the "ec2-user" and then it brings me to [ec2-user@ip-XXX ].